# Keycloak React Missing parameter code_challenge_method

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I really don't know what it is not liking but I have configured in the client Proof Key for Code Exchange Code as S256 and trying to initialize keycloak using this configuration:

```
  const keycloakConfig = {
     url: "http://localhost:8081/auth",
     realm: "project-realm",
     clientId: "project-client",
     pkceMethod: "S256",
   };
```

And it throws me this error error when trying to init it: Missing+parameter%3A+code_challenge_method

Please somebody help me, what crypto magic I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

ok found it:

use this config

```
  const keycloakConfig = {
     url: "http://localhost:8081/auth",
     realm: "project-realm",
     clientId: "project-client"
   };
```

and initialize keycloak as follows:

```
 keycloak.init({ onLoad: "login-required", pkceMethod: "S256" })
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).